# zagat content in the Places API - ERROR

Tags: google-places-api

I am many errors on my Maps API Console.

I am the website owner, not the developer or webmaster.

Got an email from Google about new pricing. Below is the email.

> Today we are announcing important changes, including our new name - Google Maps Platform, a simplified product structure, pay as you go pricing for all, and more. Please take a few minutes to review the announcement to familiarize yourself with the upcoming changes.
>
> We would like to highlight a few updates that may impact your implementation. Beginning June 11th, we are launching our new pricing plan and providing all users access to support. We’ll continue to offer a free tier — all developers will receive $200 of free monthly usage of our core products.
> How does this affect your current account(s)?
> Based on your usage over the last 3 months and our new pricing plan, we estimate that your monthly cost will exceed the current $200 free tier.

I am trying to figure out why I have so many API calls.

I am seeing in the console, that in the "Google Places API Web Service" I have alot of "Zagat content in the Places API" calls, and they all result in error.

[image: Picture of the requests and errors]

I am trying to figure out how this is happening, but not finding any info online.  I see that the "zagatselected" parameter was discarded May of 2017.  I can not figure out what is causing these errors.

Everything has been working fine, I have my own API key, and have for a long while.  The only reason I am really looking into this, is because Google will now start charging me monthly.

Comment: Zagat content was deprecated long time ago, so you shouldn't try to call it from your app.

Comment: I have the same issue. We're not calling it, it's just showing up. Calling places api for textSearch and autoComplete and it must be making further call to zagat, which we don't want regardless, since unnecessary calls, but definitely don't want to be billed for it.

Comment: This is why I am looking into it, because as far as I know we are not calling for it, it is just happening, and soon to be billed for it.

Comment: Can you post examples of Places API requests? I suspect you might be using parameters `review_summary` or `zagat_selected` that were deprecated. Also note that you have 100% errors in Zagat content. As far as I know Google charges only successful requests, errors shouldn't be charged.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you expose your Maps API key to the client, don't have  any restrictions on it, and someone else is calling the API/raising those errors?

If you have a snippet of code like this....

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEYHERE]&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initialize">
```

...on a public web page, it would be easy for someone else to take the API key and use it themselves, unless you add a IP or referrer restriction to only allow it to be used client-side from your website. You can set up restrictions on who can use your API key [following these instructions.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls)

I suspect that the new Google Maps and Places API pricing scheme (which significantly lowers the number of free Places API calls) might cause some less ethical users to use keys they can scrape off websites.

Comment: I am thinking this was maybe the possible cause of my issue. Maybe at one point the code could have been written that way, and "copied".  So as a test, I made a new API key, and I am using it, and way less calls on the new key.  But the old key is still racking up the calls.  I wish I could find out what website/program is making the calls on the original key.